# Bonjour Fails on Public Wifi

Tags: ios, sockets, bonjour

I'm building an app that uses Bonjour for device discovery on the same wifi network. I use `NSNetService` and `NSNetServiceBrowser` and it works fine on some wifi networks (like my house).

The problem is, it doesn't work on some public WiFi networks like Starbucks. The devices see themselves, but not each other. I've tried setting custom ports like 53453 or even 443. I've also let the devices choose their own ports, but nothing works.

Could someone explain what is locked down on the WiFi network that prevents the devices from seeing each other? Is there any chance I could find a port that would work on networks like this?

Comment: Many wifi access points have an option for intentionally blocking clients from communication with each other (split horizon). Is the wifi network in question perhaps using such an option? Test by checking if 2 clients on the same network can at least ping each other.

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour is built on top of multicast DNS. It's very common for public hotspots to disable multicast traffic, which would cause your application to not be able to see other instances.

Other apps will also be broken when multicast is disabled; iTunes and iPhoto sharing will suffer the same fate as your app on these networks.